# Multiple THEN for same CASE condition with union in MySQL

Tags: mysql, hql

I have a table with data some like

```
  table : foo
 ---------------------------------
 id  | A1 | B1 | C1 | D1 | A2 | B2 | ........ so on
 ----------------------------------
 abc | 2  | 4  | 6  | 7  | 3  | 4  |......... so on
 -----------------------------------
```

output i needed is

```
 id  |  Value
 ------------
 abc |  2  |
 abc |  4  |
 abc |  6  | 
 abc |  7  |
 abc |  3  |
 abc |  4  |

   ....and so on
```

Query i prepared

```
 select case when id='abc' then A1 else 0 end from foo 
 union all
 select case when id='abc' then B1 else 0 end from foo
 union all
 select case when id='abc' then C1 else 0 end from foo
 union all
 select case when id='abc' then D1 else 0 end from foo
 union all
 select case when id='abc' then A2 else 0 end from foo
 union all
 select case when id='abc' then b2 else 0 end from foo 

 .... and so on
```

i dont want my query to be so long, i want to make it dynamic with simple and short query is it possible.

Comment: You need as many unions as there are columns and if the number of columns can vary you need to build sql statements for submission to dynamic sql by accessing information_schema.columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
You don't need a case statement for this
drop table if exists t,t1;

create table t(id varchar(3),a int,b int, c int);

insert into t values
('abc',1,2,3),('def',4,5,6);

select id,a value from t
union all
select id,b from t
union all
select id,c from t
order by id;

+------+-------+
| id   | value |
+------+-------+
| abc  |     1 |
| abc  |     2 |
| abc  |     3 |
| def  |     4 |
| def  |     5 |
| def  |     6 |
+------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

BUT you do potentially have problems - with your design you cannot tell which row came from column a (column b column c etc).

In order to force row ordering in column order (from left to right) you would need a column to hold the ordinal position so that you can order by that

```
select id,1 as col,a value from t
union all
select id,2,b from t
union all
select id,3,c from t
order by id,col;
```

Ignoring problems for now if you the number of columns can change and you don't want to recode then using prepared statements , possibly in a procedure may do https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

```
set @sql = 
( 
select group_concat(
         concat('select id,', column_name, ' as value from t union all ')
         )
from
(
select table_name,column_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 't' and table_schema = 'sandbox' and column_name <> 'id'
) s
);

set @sql = (select replace(concat(substring(@sql,1,length(@sql) - 11),';'),',select','select'));

prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
execute sqlstmt;
deallocate prepare sqlstmt;
```

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested by [P.Salmon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6152400/p-salmon).

We need to use dynamic sql and to know from which column the value returns you can also add the column name in the `select` statement.

**Query:**

```
select 
    group_concat(concat("select id, '", column_name, "' as col_name, case when id = 'abc' then ", 
        column_name, " else 0 end as col_value from foo") 
        separator '\nunion all\n') 
        into @pivotcol
from (select column_name from information_schema.columns 
        where table_name  = 'foo' and column_name <> 'id') t;

prepare stmt from @pivotcol;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

**Result:**

> ```
> id  | col_name | col_value
> :-- | :------- | --------:
> abc | A1       |         2
> abc | B1       |         4
> abc | C1       |         6
> abc | D1       |         7
> abc | A2       |         3
> abc | B2       |         4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=015e962e8b41a5583bb4be72f1d03751)*